# Can single raster pixel hold more than one value?

Tags: raster, gis-principle, pixel

Can a single pixel of a raster hold more than one value?

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  A raster pixel can hold one or more values in at least two ways that I know of:

1. You can store multiple bands in a raster, so each pixel at a point can have as many values as you have bands;
2. You can encode multiple values in the pixel of a single band using [bit flags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_word).  [Bitwise operators](https://desktop.arcgis.com/search/?q=bitwise%20operators&collection=help) can be used to extract these values.  Basically, for a raster band with Byte data type, a single pixel in a single band can store 8 bits of information, each bit can store a value of either 0 or 1 so you could use 1 bit for a boolean flag, 2 bits to store values of 0-4, 3 bits can store values of 0-8, 4 bits 0-16 and so on until you use up all 8 bits in a Byte. This is how MODIS data stores [quality and cloud masks](https://modis-images.gsfc.nasa.gov/tools_bit_interpretation.html).

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong here but it is as simple as that- 8-bit integer raster hold 2^8 information space (value space). We can use this space in variety ways ie. finding some fancy coding system/flags/pattern stuff (some time ago I saw Whubers methods for encrypting information in vector geomtries!), but we will not be able to put in a cell anything else outside 0-255 range (I guess that is for unsigned integer). So, the answer depends on, what do you actually mean by value. You can have 3-band raster which would hold 3 values for the same pixel at raster level, but at band level (which is exacly 2D array-raster) you have again one space described by your raster data type.

Attribute tables are not directly connected to certain pixel (not like .shp). They collect info about classes and pixel count in class in the raster. Do not refer to any particular cell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example a raster with multiple bands can have multiple VALUES separated by a comma (as [explained by @Tomek](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/61227/115)).

You can also combine rasters using the Combine tool and the resulting attribute table would store the ATTRIBUTES of those rasters - see [Combining multiple rasters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combining-multiple-rasters.htm).

[Building raster with multiple attributes based on 3 input rasters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120216) has referenced multiple attributes as well.

You might also want to consider multidimensional rasters in the NetCDF or other formats - see [An overview of multidimensional raster data](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/an-overview-of-multidimensional-raster-data.htm).