# What is a "value raster"?

Tags: raster, spatial-database, spatial-statistics

I want to understand the concept of a "value raster" and if I can use it in neighbourhood statistics.

Comment: "value raster" is just a synonym for the raster data you want to analyse.

Answer (score 4):

It is just a synonym for the raster data you want to analyse. Unlike vector features, which are built from a geometry attribute (i.e. coordinates) and an attribute table, rasters are both geometry and attributes.

A raster is a grid of cells (pixels), each containing a VALUE (hence 'raster value'). The value can stand for whatever attribute one wishes, yet each raster represents one attribute only. E.g. one raster can be a slopes raster with its values standing for the slope in degrees or percentage; another raster will represent the aspect of a terrain in which each cell's value holds the azimuth to which a cell faces. Than another raster can be populated with categorical values, e.g. land use type, etc.

Sometime rasters can contain more than one attribute, using the concepts of **raster datasets** (or raster bands). In this case, there are several simple rasters that are combined and aligned together, thus forming a data structure which enables rasters to have more than one value per cell. Further reading on this issue and on rasters is reccomended: see [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120216/build-raster-with-multiple-attributes-based-on-3-input-rasters) and [arcgis help on raster datasets](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Raster_bands/009t00000005000000/). In addition some basic reading on [raster data from arcgis help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t00000002000000).