# Merging 2 raster one with corn data one with wheat

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3

This is my first time working with rasters outside of a class on remote sensing, Im working on learning the vocabulary and hope Im doing a ok job of it.

I would like to merge two rasters both have the same spatial extent one has number of harvested hectares for corn the other for wheat. Each raster cell has a value that gives the number of harvested hectares of corn or wheat. I would like the finished raster after the merge to show different color ramp for both corn and wheat. Each cells should show after the merge the value for harvested hectares area this could be corn or wheat. 
I have used the raster calculator to merge the two raster but this gives me one value with a the two harvested hectares summed, I need have one raster with a column for corn harvested hectares and a column for wheat with harvested hectares.

I am using arcGIS 10.3

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Area cannot be highest, yield can

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120216/build-raster-with-multiple-attributes-based-on-3-input-rasters

Comment: That is perfect that you!